# HTML form won't send a field

Tags: php, html, post, passwords

I have this form in HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost/Curso/Practica/php/InsertUser.php" method="POST"  name="usuario">
<p>Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre">Apellidos:<input type="text" name="apellidos"><br>
<p>Nick:<input type="text" name="nick"><br>
<p>Contraseña:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<p><FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="RecibirFichero.php" METHOD="post" name"SubFoto">
Foto de perfil: <INPUT NAME="FotoPerf" TYPE="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" onMouseDown="validar()">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Borrar">
</form>
```

PHP file InsertUser.php is:

```
<?php  $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];$apellidos=$_POST["apellidos"];$nick=$_POST["nick"];$password=$_POST["password"];echo($password);?>
```

The problem is that when I send data to InsertUser.php, the field "password" is empty. that means:

```
$_POST["password"]="";
```

And this message appears:

> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\Practica\php\InsertUser.php on line 14

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a form in a form.

```
<form action=...
[...]
<FORM ENCTYPE=...
```

Make sure you close a form tag before using a second one.

---

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions:

> form must not contain other form elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms and one form is inside of the other. Make it just one form.
In the input password, try putting an attribute `value=""`. It should work after you make these changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code, the first one lies in the html portion, **YOU CANNOT NEST A FORM**, so the first form tag should be whatever it is, and then close it and begin another form, secondly the proper syntax to retrieve posted values is this

```
$variable_name=$_POST['value'];
```

Please notice the use of ' and not ", try this and it should work with no hitch.